# Difference between --timeout and t.timeout in ava

Tags: node.js, ava

I am using the test framework [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) and I have two ways of setting a timeout. Either through command-line via `--timeout` and also by code via [t.timeout(..)](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/07-test-timeouts.md)

The documentation states:

> AVA resets a timer after each test, forcing tests to quit if no new test results were received within the specified timeout.

For the code `t.timeout` it says:

> These timeouts are reset each time an assertion is made.

I don't understand if I should use both, or only one timeout setting. And does `t.timeout` also mean that if I set it to `1000` milliseconds that two consecutive `t.is(..)` assertions must be made within a second otherwise the test fails?

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* to set a timeout?

It can be useful, if you know a test will have failed after N seconds, but you don't want to wait the 30 seconds before you hit a default timeout. But that only applies in specific scenarios.

Similarly, `t.timeout()` can be useful if your test does something asynchronous, and you want the test to fail if that takes too long. But again, it's rare for that to be useful.

Comment: I see, thanks! So a scenario would make scense where I set `--timeout` to certain seconds, but override a specific test with `t.timeout()`?

Comment: Yes, but please don't bother unless it's really necessary. Write tests, don't overthink it :)